# How to build LLVM doxygen in HTML ? I tried but failed

Tags: clang, llvm, doxygen

I want to get a copy of the doxygen web-pages of llvm, so I can work with it without the internet.
I did as follows:

```
$ cd LLVM_ROOT_DIR
$ mkdir out
$ cd out/
$ ../configure --enable-doxygen
$ make ENABLE_OPTIMIZED=1
```

But it only built llvm without documentation. I also tried

```
$ make BUILD_FOR_WEBSITE=1 ENABLE_OPTIMIZED=1
```

and

```
$ make ENABLE_OPTIMIZED=1 EXTRA_DIST=1
```

All of them did not work.
How could I build the web pages ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I collect the web-site by wget.

Answer (score 5):

Using recent versions of LLVM, an in-source build is prohibited by configure. Luckily the documentation can be built using [cmake](http://www.cmake.org).

```
$ mkdir out
$ cd out/
$ cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_DOXYGEN=On ../
$ make doxygen-llvm
```

The process will take a while, but after it you should have the full documentation.

Comment: This may have changed since 2015, but currently you also need to specify `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<type>` (see [the docs](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#cmake-build-type)).

Answer (score 2):

Once you enable doxygen in the configure step, you can run `make doxygen-llvm` on the `docs/` folder in your build directory.

You can run `make help` to check the available options.